# Mobile tracking google analytics and google tag manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to track how many user click the call button on the website in mobile view.
The concern is that call button is placed on two pages having same code.

I have place the below code to track the activity.but since the same code is placed on two different page. I am not able figure how many user click from which page. Page url is static it doesn't change.So we are using event tracking  the differentiate. I have attached screenshot of the GTM & Web pagecode. The line highlighted in grey in image is were the phone no. & class code ( i could not share the mobile no. & class due to security). Also i have highlighted the only  class that differ in code **( " pane-bean-additional-resources-about-trume" & pane-bean-safety-and-dosing-banner")**

```
         jQuery(".bw-mobile .ga-dosipage").click(function() { 
      try {
          dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'lear-more',
        'category': 'Call',
        'action': 'Click',
        'label': 'Page - abc'});
         } catch (err) {}
       });
```

[image]

[image]

Can any body assist me with change in code at GTM level.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If that css class is the differentiating factor you can use some JavaScript to check which version you are on. The code could look like this:

```
function getPageVersion(){
  var page = document.querySelectorAll(".pane-bean-safety-and-dosing-banner");
  if(page.length>=1){
    return "Page Version A";
  }else{
    return "Page Version B";
  }
}
```

This will return "Page Version A" if it can find that css Class on the page and return "Page Version B" if it can't. This way you can change:

```
'label': 'Page - abc'
```

to:

```
'label': getPageVersion()
```

If you want a pure GTM solution just put the code I put above in a `Custom JavaScript Variable` (don't forget to remove the function name). You can then use `{{NAME OF THE GTM JS VAR}}` in the `Event Label` part of the `Analytics Tag` and set the `Trigger` to `Click`, `any click`, enabled on the page the button is on, and filter to `Click Class contains` whatever your button class is.

Comment: Thanks Verb for your reply